# How to group lists that own one common element?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I have produced a list of sub-lists by the following:

```
pairs = Select[
   Sort[{2 #1*#2 + #2^2, #1^2 - #2^2} & @@@ 
     Flatten[Tuples /@ 
       DeleteCases[{{#}, 
           Table[If[GCD[#, i] == 1 && Mod[# - i, 3] != 0, i, 
             0], {i, # - 1}]} & /@ Range[100], 0, Infinity], 1]], 
   Plus @@ # < 120000 &];
```

In this list, every sub-list only has two elements. Now what I want to do is to group the lists in `pairs` that share one common element. For example, if `pairs={{1,2},{3,4},{2,5},{2,6},{5,4},{9,7}}`, I want to get the result like this:

```
{{{1,2},{2,5},{2,6}},{{2,5},{5,4}},{{3,4},{5,4}},{{9,7}}}
```

That is, find all the lists that have a common element, and group them. Some sub-lists may be grouped twice like `{2,5},{5,4}`, while some are alone like `{9,7}`.

I know this can be achieved easily by using the loop `For`and `While`, but I want to get a better and neater code to do this. I've tried `GatherBy[list,f]`, but I don't know how to write the function `f`. I'd appreciate it if any one could provide some ways.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your sample output seems inconsistent - either you list all elements, including those that are only present in just one pair, or you should not have things like `{{9,7}}`. Assuming the first scenario, here is a possibility:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Reap[Sow[#, #] & /@ pairs][[2]]]

(*
{        
    {{1,2}},
    {{1,2},{2,5},{2,6}},
    {{3,4}},
    {{3,4},{5,4}},
    {{2,5},{5,4}},
    {{2,6}},
    {{9,7}}
}
*)
```

You can filter out the cases with just one pair by applying `Select[#,Length[#]>1&]&` to the above result.

Comment: Thanks very much! It is what I want. In fact, I don't need to get those sub-lists like `{9,7}`.

Comment: @Z-Y.L Perhaps you want: `Cases[Reap[Sow[#, #] & /@ pairs][[2]], {_, __}]`

Answer (score 7):

```
Gather[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {5, 4}, {9, 7}},  Intersection[#1, #2] =!= {} &]
```

> {{{1, 2}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 4}}, {{9, 7}}}

But, as Leonid indicates, there is an inconsistency in your definition as the intersection operation is not transitive.

Comment: Thank you! `Gather` is more general and flexible than `GatherBy`.